# String initializer with curly braces

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have came across a piece of code making the following initialization:

```
static const uint8_t s[] = {"Some string"};
```

I would expect it to be interpreted as follows: The right side is matching an array of char pointers with single element which points to a string literal "Some string". While the left part is an array of `uint8_t`. Then the behavior I would expect is that the first element of `s` to receive some truncated value of the pointer to the string literal, thus causing unexpected behavior in the following code, assuming `s` is a string.

I've made the following test code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const uint8_t s1[] = "String1";
static const uint8_t s2[] = { "String2" };
int main(void){

    printf("%p, %p\n", s1, s2);
    printf("%s, %s\n", s1, s2);

    return 0;
}
```

For my surprise it seems that it is not happening. Not only the code will work correctly, but also the disassembly shows that both `s1` and `s2` are initialize as the corresponding strings in identical way.

Is this something `gcc` specific? Is C syntax permitting taking the single string literal into `{}` and still interpret it as a string literal?

Comment: Add a second string, and see what happen: `static const uint8_t s2[] = { "String2", "String3" };`

Comment: @LPs Yeah, tried it.

Comment: Ok, DevSolar gave you what you need.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoted from N1570 (the final draft of C11), [6.7.9 Initialization](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14) (emphasis mine):

> 14. An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>     literal or UTF-8 string literal, **optionally enclosed in braces**.
>     Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>     character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
>     initialize the elements of the array.

Comment: Ok, this is answering the question explicitly. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The sun qingyao's answer correctly mentions that you can add extra braces to such initializer. It's worth to mention this does not only apply to arrays:

```
int x = { 0 };
```

[compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79289b35f4d99763) even though the element being initialized is not an array. This is thanks to the following [clause](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11):

> 6.7.9.11
> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.

But why would such thing be allowed? The answer is, this makes possible to initialize values with a single syntax:

```
T x = { 0 };
```

works for any `T` and zero-initializes everything (for structs, every member, for arrays, every element, for scalar types, just initializes the value).

Comment: You can add a reference: `11 The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.`

Comment: @sun qingyao I think just that reference would qualify as a full answer. Though technically the initialized entity is not a scalar....